# Aligning subcaptions within a while loop

Tags: subfloats

I am trying to display multiple images with similar names, but the alignment of the last row is off seemingly regardless of what I try:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{subcaption,graphicx}
\newcounter{i}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \makeatletter
    \setcounter{i}{0}
    \@whilenum\value{i}<9\do {
        \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{test_\thei}
        \end{subfigure}%
        \stepcounter{i}
    }
    \makeatother
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: misaligned images]

Comment: Note that (almost) any line that ends with at { or } adds a space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `\unskip` after the closing brace and protect other endlines. By the way, you don't need `subfigure` for this application.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcounter{i}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \makeatletter
    \setcounter{i}{0}%
    \@whilenum\value{i}<9\do {%
      \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-1x1}%
      \stepcounter{i} % <--- note the space before %
    }\unskip
    \makeatother
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Change back the file names of the images.

The space after `\stepcounter{i}` produces a space in output and you want to remove the last one.  If a single space is not enough, do

```
\stepcounter{i}\quad
```

or

```
\stepcounter{i}\hspace{<whatever lenght you want>}% <--- the % is necessary
```

---

A different implementation:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}

\usepackage{showframe}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\integercaseTF}{mm+m+m}
 {
  \int_case:nnTF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\intloop}{O{1}+mO{1}+m}
 {
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { #1 } { #3 } { #2 } { #4 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\setlength{\lineskip}{0.025\columnwidth}

\intloop{9}{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.3\columnwidth]{test-#1}%
  \integercaseTF{#1}{{3}{\\} {6}{\\} {9}{\\}}{}{\hfil}%
}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The `\integercaseTF` command takes four arguments: the first is an integer expression, here the current integer in the loop; the second argument is a list of cases, in this case we say that if the current integer in the loop is 3, 6 or 9 then `\\` should be issued; the third argument is additional code to be executed in case of a match; the fourth argument is additional code to be executed in case of no match, in this case we want `\hfil`.

The current integer in the loop is available as `#1` in the code for `\intloop`, whose syntax is

```
\intloop[<optional start>]{<mandatory end>}[<optional step>]{<code>}
```

so, for example, `\intloop[0]{5}[2]{...}` would execute `...` for the integer values 0,2,4 (because we requested to go up to 5, starting from 0 with step 2).

The setting to `\lineskip` to `0.025\columnwidth` is so that successive pictures in the block will have as much vertical as horizontal space between them. The pictures occupy 90% of the horizontal space and we want to divide the remaining space in four equal parts, so also the `\lineskip` should be 2.5% of the text width.

[image]

[image]

`showframe is just to better see the white space in context.

Answer (score 0):

Or, insert 3 subfigures at a time using the inner loop, then add a `\par`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{subcaption,graphicx}
\newcounter{i}
\newcounter{j}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \makeatletter
    \setcounter{i}{0}
    \@whilenum\value{i}<3\do {
        \setcounter{j}{0}
        \@whilenum\value{j}<3\do {%
            \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
            \end{subfigure}%
            \stepcounter{j}
            \stepcounter{i}
        }
        \par
    }
    \makeatother
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]